# RESTLET: When running restful my connections to JAX-WS are blocked

Tags: jax-ws, restlet

Using the latest restlet framework (Java SE) and also Jax-WS (also just in Java SE), connections to the restful service work ok, but connections to the WS side never make a connection, client is always reporting an error. As soon as I stop the restful side, all works ok again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, there is no issue here. But in case anyone is interested this is my test java to prove it works ok...

```
  public class Example
  {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Example example = new Example();
        /* Start Restful */
        example.startRestful();
        /* Start JAX-WS */
        example.startJAXWS();
     }

     public void startRestful() throws Exception {
        // create a new Component
        Component component = new Component();
        // add a new HTTP server listening on port specified
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 9998);
        // attach the manager
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("/abc", new RestfulRouter(new Restful()));
        // start the component  
        component.start();
     }

     public void startJAXWS() throws Exception {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorld());
     }

     @WebService
     public class HelloWorld
     {
        @WebMethod
        public String sayHelloWorld(String name) {
           System.out.println("JAX-WS working");
           return "Hello World " + name;
        }
     }

     public class RestfulRouter extends Application
     {
        private Restful webService;

        public RestfulRouter(Restful webService) {
           this.webService = webService;
        }

        @Override
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            // create a router Restlet that routes each call to the console
            Router router = new Router(getContext());
            // attach the route to the webService Restlet 
            router.attachDefault(webService);
            return router;
        }
     }

     public class Restful extends Restlet
     {
        @Override
        public void handle(final Request request, final Response response)  
        {
           String name = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm().getFirstValue("name");  
           System.out.println("Restful working");
           response.setEntity(name, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        }
     }
  }
```